# ImageMagick: convert to keep same name for converted image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am converting .psd to .png files inside folder with one. How to keep same name of every file in folder with different extension ?

For example I enter in folder images and then from terminal I execute

```
$ convert *.psd *.png
```

but it gives names to .png just numbers not the same as appropriate .psd image.

Comment: You should accept @emcconville's answer over mine, because it is platform independent.

Comment: I can't decipher your English...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use the `-set` and formatting options.

```
convert *.psd -set filename:base "%[basename]" "%[filename:base].png"
```

See "[Long Form Attribute Percent Escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)" and "[Filename Percent Escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes)" docs.

**Update**

The [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) utility that ships with imagemagick can also be used.

```
mogrify -format png *.psd
```

Note: Be careful with mogrify as the docs state...

> This tool is similiar to convert except that the original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the -format option) with any changes you request.

Comment: Just an update: `base` is now called `basename`. With that substitution, works as expected!

Comment: -> `convert *.psd -set filename:base "%[basename]" "%[filename:base].png"`

Comment: `mogrify -format png *.psd` works as the best, BTW you can add is as Action on `Thunar` file manger `mogrify -format png %F`

Answer (score 15):

If you are on Linux, Unix or Mac OSX, you could use in a terminal window with Bash shell:

```
for i in *.psd; do
     convert $i ${i/.psd/.png}
done
```

---

<sub>I deliberately do not advertise `mogrify` any more. It is too dangerous for every user who doesn't know it already, and who comes to this website to ask for help. `mogrify` is overwriting your original files in some cases (of course not when converting PSD->PNG)</sub>

Answer (score 14):

Or, even simpler:

```
mogrify -format png *.psd
```

Comment: That's right, mogrify with `-format` will do the same thing.

Comment: Note that at v7 of **ImageMagick**, that becomes `magick mogrify -format png *.psd`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, that works. Is there a way to place the output into a subfolder? Can't figure it out.

Comment: @Eskel Yes. `mkdir OUTPUT; magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -format png *.psd`

Answer (score 5):

I like the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27784462/5645583),

that being said, in later versions of ImageMagick, the command is

```
convert *.psd -set filename:basename "%[basename]" "%[filename:basename].png"
```

as also mentioned by @jan-glx and @jomel imperio