# Batch command for ImageMagick to crop width of all files in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have hundreds of images in a folder of size 1920x~100,000. I need to cut out the middle 900p of every file leaving the height unaffected. how do I pass each file to this command? `magick convert image.jpg -crop 900x+510+0 result.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. use `mogrify` instead of `convert` to replace the image with the result
2. Let IM [deduce the output file from the input fil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778870/imagemagick-convert-to-keep-same-name-for-converted-image):

```
convert *.jpg -crop 900x+510+0 -set filename:base "%[basename]" "%[filename:base]-cropped.jpg"
```

(or use a similar idiom to target a different directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
md "destinationdirectory" 2>nul
pushd "sourcedirectory"
for %%e in (*.jpg) do magick convert "%%e" -crop 900x+510+0 "destinationdirectory\%%e"
popd
```

simply substitute your directory names for `sourcedirectory` and `destinationdirectory` - and they can't be the same directory.