# ImageMagick multiple commands w/varying source and destination folders and files

Tags: imagemagick

Is there a way to replace a sequence of Magick commands like:

```
magick folder1/1.jpg[80x100] folder2/1.jpg
magick folder3/2.jpg[80x100] folder4/2.jpg
...
magick folder9/xyz.jpg[80x100] folder10/xyz.jpg
```

into a single invocation of magick with all the commands in a single file, as in:

```
magick @command.lst
```

where "command.lst" is a text file that contains:

```
folder1/1.jpg[80x100] folder2/1.jpg
folder3/2.jpg[80x100] folder4/2.jpg
...
folder9/xyz.jpg[80x100] folder10/xyz.jpg
```

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: You can also make a plain shell script (.bat, .sh, depending on your OS) with multiple `magick` commands. You can also have [one single magick command that applies to a pattern, and output names "computed" from the input names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27784462/6378557).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, those suggestions don't work for me. The first one means reloading magick for every conversion. I'm invoking it from within a C program, so I was trying to avoid reloading it for every conversion. The second one doesn't help either because the folders containing the files may vary from one command to the next.

Comment: In modern OSes, the reload of the executable is negligible compared to loading/writing the images, the code is in cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a bunch of commands in a script similar to this and call it `script.mgk`:

```
a.jpg -resize 10x10 -write c.jpg -delete 0
b.jpg -resize 10x10 -write d.jpg -delete 0
```

Then invoke it with:

```
magick -script script.mgk
```

---

If you don't actually want to create a physical file on disk, you can create the commands dynamically and pipe them into **ImageMagick**'s `stdin` like this:

```
{ 
   echo "-size 64x48 xc:black -write a.jpg +delete"
   echo "-size 32x24 xc:blue  -write b.png"
} | magick -script -
```

Or, you can use a `bash` *"heredoc"* like this:

```
cat <<EOF | magick -script -
-size 64x48 xc:black -write a.jpg +delete
-size 32x24 xc:blue  -write b.png
EOF
```