# Rename file using xargs -a file

Tags: linux, sed, rename, xargs

I have several files:

```
test1.log
test2.log
test3.log
test.txt
```

test.txt contains:

```
./test1.log
./test2.log
./test3.log
```

I want to be able to use my:

`test.txt`

with

xargs -a test.txt ......

to rename

```
 test1.log
 test2.log
 test3.log
```

to .txt files:

```
 test1.txt
 test2.txt
 test3.txt
```

Is there a way of doing so with rename,sed,sub,or awk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch renaming files in command line and Xargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972002/batch-renaming-files-in-command-line-and-xargs)

Comment: `rename 's/\.log\z/.txt/' $(cat test.txt)`

Comment: that never worked, thanks though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer at this link:

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8368/bulk-rename-files-with-sed-one-liner

It isn't exactly what I wanted to do, but it works:

```
ls *.log | sed -e 'p;s/.log/.txt/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

Answer (score 1):

If your sed skills are not as strong or you want to use the base of the name multiple times in a general way, the following strips the extension and then allows just constructing the command from the file name without the extension.

```
ls **/*.txt | sed 's/\.txt$//' | xargs -n1 -i mv {}.txt {}.md
```

The **/*.txt uses the bash shopt globstar to include the sub directories.  If you don't have the globstar shopt enabled, you can replace "ls **/*.txt" with an instance of the find command.